# Why symlinking pam_unix.so to pam_unix_acct.so and other three files?

Tags: pam

On CentOS, pam_unix.so is linked to the following 4 files:

```
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   11 Oct 11  2016 pam_unix_acct.so -> pam_unix.so*
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   11 Oct 11  2016 pam_unix_auth.so -> pam_unix.so*
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   11 Oct 11  2016 pam_unix_passwd.so -> pam_unix.so*
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   11 Oct 11  2016 pam_unix_session.so -> pam_unix.so*
```

I tried to do things like `grep -R pam_unix_passwd /etc/`, but pam.d does not seem to be using it.

What's the point of those files?

Comment: I don't know about PAM (hence a comment) but having files behave differently depending on their name is a common trick. Look at how `bash` behaves differently if called through a symlink named `sh` or how the same `bysybox` executable behaves as whatever name you call it as (`awk`, `sed`, etc.). I'm guessing there's something similar going on here and `pam_unix.so*` behaves differently depending on how it is named. Also, what directory are you listing there?

Comment: @terdon /usr/lib64/security/, same directory for pam_unix.so